# Creating a TD elements within a TR element with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Every time I run this script:

```
document.getElementById("billTable").appendChild(nextRow)
document.getElementById("billTable").appendChild(LISTname);
document.getElementById("billTable").appendChild(LISTprice);
document.getElementById("billTable").appendChild(LISTremove);
```

It creates:

```
<tr></tr><td>L - Meat Lovers Pizza</td><td>$6.70</td><td>X</td>
```

I am trying to make it so the TD tags are with in the TR.

Comment: I assume `billTable` is the `<table>`, if so, you are targeting the wrong elkement, you must target the `<tr>`

Comment: You need to append the `td` elements to `tr` not the `table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `nextRow` contains the `tr` element, so you should be appending to that, not the table:

```
nextRow.appendChild(LISTname);
nextRow.appendChild(LISTprice);
nextRow.appendChild(LISTremove);
document.getElementById("billTable").appendChild(nextRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

use insertCell() instead

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = "List Name";
cell2.innerHTML = "List Price";
```